# How to go back a line in IPython after having hit the left arrow key

Tags: python, ipython

I'm using IPython, which is great other than in the following scenario:

- I go back a line
- I hit the left arrow key to start editing that line
- I realise that I didn't go back far enough
- I hit the up arrow key
- IPython won't let me go back a line
- I have to delete the entire line in order to be able to start going back through lines again, and the line I just deleted cannot be travelled back to in the future

How can I prevent this from happening? How can I keep going back even after hitting that pesky left arrow key? Is there a setting somewhere I can set?

(I'm using IPython 2.4.1 in Anaconda 2.1.0 and Python 2.7.9 on OS X 10.10.2.)

Comment: it works for me, ipython 1.2.1 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: probably you want to take a look at `readline` documentation.

Comment: I think it's the same feature that lets you type `foo` and then press up to get to the last line starting with foo. Once you've done anything within a line, it treats that as a prefix for history search. This is a readline feature that IPython simply enables. You should be able to override it with the correct setting in `.inputrc`, but I'm not sure what that setting would be.

Comment: If you press the end key or the right arrow key several times to get to the end of the input, does the up key work again?

Comment: DaveP: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Can anyone point me at the relevant part of the `readline` documentation or the location of `.inputrc`?